# Is it possible to display the full text of a dropdown option in Chrome using the default select element?

Tags: css, html-select, dropdown

Really simple question here but not sure where to find answer. I have a site that in Safari displays the entire text of a dropdown option by wrapping the text and expanding the height of the select element. By default in Chrome, the text gets cut off once the maximum width of the element has been reached. I know there are limitations to how much styling can be done on the default select element but I am wondering if what I see in Safari can be reproduced in Chrome.

I have tried adding many css styles that I hoped would wrap the text instead of cut it.

```
select {
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

I threw everything I had at it, and I still can't seem to get the text to wrap. Is it even possible in Chrome? Is there a place in the Chrome docs that addresses this question?

Here is a codepen I started though its not possible to cross-browser test in codepen unless you have the pro version.
Here's an inline link to [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/KasiaMcMahon/pen/RzLMZe).

Comment: if you want consist looking `select`'s across browsers the best thing to do would be to implement a custom dropdown plugin like [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: @zgood thank you for the suggestion, but in this case I am looking for information on what is possible using only the default select element.

Comment: Well, good luck because I don't think want you want is possible, but I could be wrong!